# How to turn on pseudo localization inside Android Studio?

Tags: android, localization

I can't find document on how to enable pseudo localization inside Android Studio? I want to use pseudo L10N to find any overflow/truncation/wrapping/hardcoded strings in the app.

I tried modify the build.gradle to add "pseudoLocalesEnabled true" to the debug build section, however, when I tried to install the apk on device, I keep getting failing to parse the package error. When that line is removed, the apk installs fine.

How to turn on pseudo localization feature inside Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/04/19/pseudo-localization-testing-in-android/) says that your device needs to be running on Android 5.0 or later and that you need to have developer options enabled to access the pseudo-localization locales. You also need gradle version 0.14.2 or later.

And if you can't get this to work within Android Studio you could try to use a service like [babble-on](http://www.ibabbleon.com/pseudolocalization.html) to get your strings pseudo-localized.